# Parsing a PHP array with multiple nests

Tags: php

I'm a newb and looking for some help parsing a PHP array. I have generated the following array and it is saved in:

```
$items = $pocket->retrieve($params, $accessToken);
```

As you can see, each item has a status attribute which is either 0 or 1. I'm looking for a simple way to loop through each item and find out how many have status 0 and how many have status 1.

I've tried to use a simple foreach but with no success. The problem is, nothing is returned so I do not think I am parsing the array properly.

If I do a simple print_r it prints out the array.

```
print_r($items);
```

What I have so far:

```
$items = $pocket->retrieve($params, $accessToken);
$hasRead = 0;
$hasNotRead = 0;

foreach ($items as $key) {

    if ($key["status"] == 1) {
        $hasRead++;
    }
    else {
        $hasNotRead++;
    }

    echo "Read = " . $hasRead;
    echo "Not Rad = " . $hasNotRead;

}
```

Any help much appreciated!

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [complete] => 1
    [list] => Array
        (
            [666040191] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 666040191
                    [resolved_id] => 666040191
                    [given_url] => https://medium.com/matter/my-life-with-piper-from-big-house-to-small-screen-592b35f5af94
                    [given_title] => The Other True Story Behind ‘Orange Is The New Black’
                    [favorite] => 0
                    [status] => 0
                    [time_added] => 1405415236
                    [time_updated] => 1405415236
                    [time_read] => 0
                    [time_favorited] => 0
                    [sort_id] => 0
                    [resolved_title] => My Life with Piper: From Big House to Small Screen
                    [resolved_url] => https://medium.com/matter/my-life-with-piper-from-big-house-to-small-screen-592b35f5af94
                    [excerpt] => I was 29 years old and living the dream, or at least my version of it, when everything changed. I was in love with an amazing woman and had a rent-controlled sublet in New York City’s West Village and a good job at a glossy magazine.
                    [is_article] => 1
                    [is_index] => 0
                    [has_video] => 0
                    [has_image] => 1
                    [word_count] => 10066
                )

            [665694007] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 665694007
                    [resolved_id] => 665694007
                    [given_url] => http://digg.com/video/weird-al-yankovic-parodies-pharrells-happy
                    [given_title] => http://digg.com/video/weird-al-yankovic-parodies-pharrells-happy
                    [favorite] => 0
                    [status] => 0
                    [time_added] => 1405415180
                    [time_updated] => 1405415180
                    [time_read] => 0
                    [time_favorited] => 0
                    [sort_id] => 1
                    [resolved_title] => Weird Al Yankovic Parodies Pharrell's 'Happy'
                    [resolved_url] => http://digg.com/video/weird-al-yankovic-parodies-pharrells-happy
                    [excerpt] => Weird Al does a one-shot spoof of Pharrell's ubiquitous "Happy" with some surprise help from a few celebrities.
                    [is_article] => 1
                    [is_index] => 0
                    [has_video] => 0
                    [has_image] => 0
                    [word_count] => 18
                )

            [664691248] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 664691248
                    [resolved_id] => 664691252
                    [given_url] => http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/07/13/an-investigation-into-the-delicious-origins-of-ice-cream.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+thedailybeast%2Farticles+%28The+Daily+Beast+-+Latest+Articles%29
                    [given_title] => http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/07/13/an-investigation-into-the-
                    [favorite] => 0
                    [status] => 0
                    [time_added] => 1405415169
                    [time_updated] => 1405415169
                    [time_read] => 0
                    [time_favorited] => 0
                    [sort_id] => 2
                    [resolved_title] => An Investigation Into the Delicious Origins of Ice Cream
                    [resolved_url] => http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/07/13/an-investigation-into-the-delicious-origins-of-ice-cream.html
                    [excerpt] => Thirty years ago this week, Ronald Reagan made perhaps the most momentous decision of his presidency. "Ice cream is a nutritious and wholesome food," he declared on July 9, 1984. "It enjoys a reputation as the perfect dessert and snack."
                    [is_article] => 1
                    [is_index] => 0
                    [has_video] => 0
                    [has_image] => 0
                    [word_count] => 1262
                )

        )

    [error] => 
    [search_meta] => Array
        (
            [search_type] => normal
        )

    [since] => 1405421539
)
```

Comment: yes, foreach loop is the right way. Looks like you didn't try anything, otherwise you'd have shown the code(!)

Comment: see my edit to include code I've written. I think my foreach is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to iterate over **list** array right?

```
$items = $pocket->retrieve($params, $accessToken);
$hasRead = 0;
$hasNotRead = 0;

foreach ($items['list'] as $key) { //Added list

    if ($key["status"] == 1) {
        $hasRead++;
    }
    else {
        $hasNotRead++;
    }

}

echo "Read = " . $hasRead;
echo "Not Rad = " . $hasNotRead;
```

Comment: Another quick question - if I was looking at trying to figure out - "how many articles are being read per day" - would that be similiarly simple? There is a $list[time_read] value, so perhaps I could parse those?